# Unity3D GetComponent with Generics

Tags: c#, generics, unity-game-engine

I want to write a util method to obtain a component on a given game object. it looks like this ...

```
    public static MonoBehaviour FindAndAssignComponent<T>(string name)
    {
        GameObject g = GameObject.Find(name);
        if (g != null) return g.GetComponent<T>();
        return null;
    }
```

The problem is with `GetComponent`! How can i use the generic `T` with it so that it understand it? `<typeof(T)>` doesn't work, neither does `GetComponent(T)` or `GetComponent(typeof(T))`.

Comment: I don't have unity at the moment but what error are you getting? Is it a compile time error? If so odds are you're missing constraints on T as i assume GetComponent would only be valid for T that implement a certain interface. What is the signature of GetComponent like?*

Comment: First, your return type needs to be `T` to match what `GetComponent<T>` returns. Is `g` getting the value you expect (ie- not `null`)? Is there a component of type `T` available in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the `where` clause, and fix your return to be `Component`

```
public static Component FindAndAssignComponent<T>(string name) where T : Component
{
    GameObject g = GameObject.Find(name);
    if (g != null) return g.GetComponent<T>();
    return null;
}
```

Also the name of your method is a little misleading... your not really assigning the component, your just retrieving one that already exists. perhaps you meant to do this:

```
public static void FindAndAssignComponent<T>(string name) where T : Component
{
    GameObject g = GameObject.Find(name);
    if (g == null)
        throw new ObjectNotFoundException(String.Format("GameObject '{0}' not found in hierarchy!", name));
    g.AddComponent<T>();
}
```